# JSP Reading response body after HTTP GET request to URL

Tags: java, jsp, http

In the msisdn Lookup API documentation it says

> By default, the results of the request lookups are available in the body of the  response in a line-by-line, key=value format. For example, a typical response I might receive after sending request is as follows:
>
> `--START:447777777777 status="ok" mcc="234" mnc="02"`
>   `operatorname="O2" isoalpha3code="GBR" END:447777777777--`

I sent request with the relevant parameters such that I want to get information of msisdn "447766551112"

URL with parameter example

```
http://api.txtnation.com/Networks/Lookup?username=user123&password=pwd123&
msisdn=447766551112
```

my Code

```
String addParam=java.net.URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")
                        + "="
                        + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8")
                        + "&"
                        + java.net.URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")
                        + "="
                        + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")
                        + "&"
                        + java.net.URLEncoder.encode("msisdn", "UTF-8")
                        + "="
    + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(msisdn, "UTF-8")

java.net.URL msisdnLookup= new java.net.URL("http://api.txtnation.com/Networks
/LookUp/?"+addParam);

java.net.HttpURLConnection mmpostback = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) 
msisdnLookup.openConnection();
mmpostback.setDoOutput(true);
mmpostback.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

It shows me HTTP response :OK

```
System.out.println(mmpostback.getResponseMessage());
```

I receive "status", "mcc", "mnc" after requests.. but it shows me NULl value. In API it says , it's in the body of response.. but how can I find these?

```
status=request.getParameter("status");
mcc=request.getParameter("mcc");
mnc=request.getParameter("mnc");
```

I even tried reading parameters and headers but I couldn't find the above names- status, mcc, mnc, operatorname,isoalpha3code

How can I read the request body in jsp according to what API documentation says above? How to read line by line, key=value? Please suggest